# How to release an iOS App only for members with an external membership?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am planning to release an iOS App for customers which already have a contract/membership for my services and also pay for it.

I have tried to search for such informations but suffer to find some satisfying answers.

The Point: I know apple wants that the payment goes through them or their store, but I already charge my customers for the services and I just want my services to be available on iOS devices aswell.

Will i get rejected when i try to build an iOS-App with a login without registration/payment on the app itself or in-app?

Same question on android platform..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you already have paid user base, then you can identify those transaction ids mapping to their userID/Email/Phone numbers etc. Through which you can create credentials for specific users.
Give registration option for others & show what services you offer within app.Further you can ask for payment within app or through your payment gateway.

Comment: hi thank you for answering, I dont want the payment to go through apple at all! Wethere it is on iOS-App-store or in-app payment. Have you done such an app before or where do you find such suggestions? I also do not want other users to be able to register, because I do contracts with them in live. My User base has accounts and stuff, but on website only. I just want to provide them an app with same services. Will i get trouble with apple conditions?

Comment: Then Best solution for you to release your app as Enterprise application in which you can keep app on your server & allow to download for paid users via your website.

Comment: hi elle, no sorry it is not helpful :)